# Why subTasks not created in my task runner explorer?

Tags: gulp

I am working on my Gulp tutorial(using this site: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx).

Here is gulpFile.js:

```
    // include plug-ins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');

var config = {
    //Include all js files but exclude any min.js files
    src: ['app/**/*.js', '!app/**/*.min.js']
}

//delete the output file(s)
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    //del is an async function and not a gulp plugin (just standard nodejs)
    //It returns a promise, so make sure you return that from this task function
    //  so gulp knows when the delete is complete
    return del(['app/all.min.js']);
});

// Combine and minify all files from the app folder
// This tasks depends on the clean task which means gulp will ensure that the 
// Clean task is completed before running the scripts task.
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function () {

    return gulp.src(config.src)
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    return gulp.watch(config.src, ['scripts']);
});

//Set a default tasks
gulp.task('default', ['scripts'], function () { });
```

Here is task runner explorer:

[image]

And here how task runner explorer looks in tutorial site above:

[image]

Any idea why I dont see subTasks in my task runner explorer?

Comment: Same here. Running VS 2015. The tutorial is using older version of VS, given that the author mentioned having to install a Task Runner Explorer plugin, which is already built in for VS 2015.

Comment: Same here running VS 2015 Update 3

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way so far that I've been able to fix this.

After adding a task, rename your gulpfile to something else and then close Task Runner Explorer.

Change the renamed file back to gulpfile.js, then reopen Task Runner Explorer.

You should see your gulpfile tasks updated.